# Possible meanings for "気を巡らせる"

Tags: meaning

I'd like to know the possible meanings for "気を巡らせる" . The term is from a Drama CD I'm currently listening, its a fantasy story with magic and the sort.

The context is a fight, the main character use balls as projectiles that hits his opponent nicknamed "Steel Whirlwind", but he withstands it and counter attacks.

I'll try to transcript the scene after that:

> -「吾輩の固体を縛るのではなく、砕こうと言う腹であったようだ。惜しいか。傷ついた貴様の攻撃では、吾輩の筋肉を貫通をすることは叶わなかったようだな。」
>
> -「ええ, ですから…最初から貫通を狙ってはいませんでした。」
>
> -「何？？」
>
> -「私の気を巡らせたボール, それは… 」
>
> (Sound of balls appearing in the air)
>
> -「…吾輩が囲まれている。打ったのではなく、最初から吾輩の周囲に巻いていたというのか？」
>
> -「その通り。鋼の旋風, あなたの歩みを止めるのが目的! 」

I know "巡らせる" combined with "思い" means "to ponder", but I don't know what it means combined with "気". Also, I've found that "気をめぐらす" is used a lot in articles about oriental health practices, which confuse me more.

For example: "気をめぐらせて心身デトックス！初心者でも超カンタン気功体操！"

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

気を巡らす（せる） almost solely stands for "to circulate / surround with qi". Yes, that [qi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qi). Although there are idioms with similar word forms such as 思い巡らす, 考えを巡らす, 気を回す etc., I have never seen that this specific phrase is used in such meaning.

What the phrase actually refers to is completely up to what "qi" is defined to be in each context, but I can say with confidence that it is not any figure of speech for a certain everyday mental activity.

Comment: Perhaps it's worth noting that 気 is used pretty loosely today, and it can safely be translated as "energy", "power", "force" or maybe even "mana" when an oriental flavor is not relevant.