# Meaning of 怒りの気

Tags: words

I found the expression in the following phrase:

> なんでも猟師が発見した石は、蝦夷の言うところによると、こんじんさまの**怒りの気**なのだとか。　それを掘り返すなど、望んで祟りを招くに等しいと.

I googled it and although I didn't find a dictionary entry there were many results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

気【き】 ("[qi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qi)") means something like "energy", "force" or "aura". 怒りの気 usually refers to that dark aura emitted from a mad person.

[image: aura]

See: [Possible meanings for "気を巡らせる"](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/73789/5010)

Of course a stone is not aura itself, so we don't usually say 石は怒りの気だ. Instead, we say 石には怒りの気が宿っている or 石には怒りの気が込められている. I don't know why this person said 石は怒りの気だ. Maybe the author made a mistake, or maybe it's highly "condensed" aura that looks almost like a stone?

Comment: Forgive me for asking this as it's a bit tangential to the question, but do you find the comma placement after など to be odd (if それを掘り返すなど is meant to be parsed with 望んで)? Or is 望んで some special adverb that has no relevance to what comes before?

Comment: @user26484 This など is a formal version of なんて and working as an emphatic topic particle. https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/33296/5010

Comment: I'm aware of its function; I'm simply curious as to why they split the sentence like that if それを掘り返すなど、望んで is meant to be treated as a single unit.

Comment: @user26484 Ah sorry. This 望んで is "intentionally" or "willingly" and modifies 祟りを招く. "Digging it up is the same as invoking a curse *willingly*".

Comment: Ah, that makes sense then. I Googled to see if 望んで had any dictionary entries detailing it as such, but nothing came of it. I should've intuited that it meant that, anyways, given that 進んで seems to be used in a very similar manner. Thanks for clarifying!